# associative arrays' ".keys()"

Tags: bash

In Bash (v4+):

```
$ declare -A x=([foo]=bar [coconut]=banana)
$ echo ${x[@]}
```

gives:

```
banana bar
```

What can I type to get this:

```
foo coconut
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can preceed `x` in `echo ${x[@]}` with a `!` to get keys:

```
echo ${!x[@]}
```

More information on associative arrays: http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/